# Does Akka support in-process messaging without object serialization?

Tags: java, events, serialization, akka, actor

Looking to use Akka Actors to communicate events between Java threads in the same JVM. Some of these events contain large objects (10-100Mb). I want to avoid serializing these objects while saving memory space by passing only a reference to the object; does Akka support this? I understand it's possible to [implement](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/serialization.html) a custom Akka serializer, and that could be a solution, but beyond that I don't know much else about the framework.

Comment: Passing a reference implies shared state between threads, which is completely anathema to the message-passing model.

Comment: I know, but the objects I'm passing contain immutable values, it's pointless to serialize and reconstitute them between actors, so I take it the answer is no?

Comment: Shared state is no problem as long as it's not mutable.  The problem is _shared mutable state_.  Ditch either one of shared or mutable and you're on firmer ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Akka treats local message passing as an optimization, bypassing the remoting machinery which includes the message serializer.  See [location transparency](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/remoting.html).

Comment: I just tested this, and you are correct; the object sent was the same as the object received based on memory address.

Comment: Is there any place where this is documented?